# How to redirect to another Tiles layout in Struts2?

Tags: java, struts2, tiles

I'm using Tiles in my Struts2 web app. I have page where I display all records. I use a tiles layout for displaying all the records. Now, if I click a delete on one of the records, it should display me the same page again without the one I deleted. I am able to delete the record, but I'm not sure to how to forward to same tile layout back again to display all the records again. How to do this in my struts.xml ? Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research and looks like there is no way to forward tiles. Instead, I used action redirect. Following is a snippet if it helps any one.

```
<action name="deleteSurvey" class="masonsurvey.DeleteAction">
  <result name="deleteSuccess" type="redirectAction">
    ListSurvey
  </result>
</action>
```